# Inference/Prediction using a skewed sample of a population?

Tags: prediction, inference, sample, population, out-of-sample

In statistics, the number one assumption for inference/prediction is to have a random sample that represents the target population. What if our sample is a skewed sample that does not truly represent the target population? One example of a skewed sample might be breast cancer patients. What if our sample has too many (or too few) breast cancer positive patients compared to the actual population?

My question is whether there is any line of research to deal with these types of samples and yet still do a robust inference/prediction on the true population?

Comment: Do you know the direction and magnitude of the skew? can you estimate the probability that a particular individual is sampled?

Comment: @ssdecontrol good questions. Yes, I know the direction of the skew. and No, I don't know the probability of each individual being sampled.